# Tablecell with video display

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, video, ios6

I am looking to create a playlist format tableview controller page that has videos in the cells. When the disclosure button is clicked, the video plays and so on. Any ideas on how to go about this?..Or a link to a good tutorial on it? 
I have been cracking my head on this..spending so much time surfing the web to no avail ..
any help will be much appreciated and voted
thanks

here's my sample code..i do know it might not be the best way to go about it, hence it isn't work working

here is my header file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

 @interface BIDVideosViewController : UIViewController

 <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *tableList;

 @end
```

Here is my .m file

```
 #import "BIDVideosViewController.h"

 @interface BIDVideosViewController ()
 {
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

 }

  @end

  @implementation BIDVideosViewController

  @synthesize tableList;

  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[table setDelegate:self];
[table setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:table];
tableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gangan",@"SwimGood", nil];
self.tableList = array;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 return [tableList count];
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *DisclosureButtonIdentifier = @"DisclosurebutotonIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DisclosureButtonIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonIdentifier];
}
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *rowString = [tableList objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = rowString;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Gangan" ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
  moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                   name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(endPlay:)
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(stopBusyIndicator:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault; //'movieControlMode' is deprecated

//moviePlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(212, 84, 600, 600);

 [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];       
 [moviePlayer play];                           </i>
```

Comment: You want to play the video inside the cell or in other controller after hitting disclosure button?

Comment: I want to play the video after hitting the disclosure button, just like how youtube would work @Deepak

Comment: Oh! so you can go for MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add MediaPLayer framework.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;   
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification 
                                                           object:moviePlayer];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(endPlay:) 
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                           object:moviePlayer];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(stopBusyIndicator:) 
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                           object:moviePlayer];

                moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit; 
                moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
                //moviePlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

                    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(212, 84, 600, 600);

                }
                [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
                [moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this, one thing though!..what method i put this in and what do i need to remove from my code to replace this with @Deepak

Comment: mmmm! you can write this in didSelectRowAtIndex but keep in mind of optimization of code.
I mean do keep in mind memory optimization.

Comment: @Deepak..hey man i the errors but nothing shows up on the app, not even the disclosure buttons..pls help

Comment: Hey @dappa are you sure that your url which you are passing to MPMoviePlayer is all correct.
I mean i am not getting what problem you are exactly facing?

Comment: hello mate, the problem I am having i that the disclosure buttons do not work, i.e, when i click on them to play my video nothing happens, the string name of my video appears as well as the disclosure button, but it is not functioning, any idea on where i am at fault matey ? @Deepak